# UINavigationController not being animated as wanted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller

Well, I have a tab based app with a navigationController for each tab. When I am at the root of each navigationController and I push a view, the animation runs perfect, but when I am on a pushed view and I want to pop it the navigationController gets animated but not the view. This is what I use to pop it:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and to push it:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:activityController animated:YES];
```

any suggestion?

EDIT:

I have a tableView  in the root controller. Every time I select a row I run this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ActivityViewController *activityController = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButonItem"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButonItem_Pressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 55, 30)];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    activityController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
    activityController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:activityController animated:YES];
}
```

and this is my popBack method:

```
- (void) popBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I think we need more code. How are you setting up your view?

Comment: @Plenilune there you have some code ;)

Comment: try this [self.navigationController popToViewController:yourController Animated:YES];

Comment: @sreecharan same thing happens using that

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:YES];
```

It seems to have solved the problem for a lot of people.